# No Items shown in ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to add a UserSontrol to an ItemsControl for each user I have in my viewmodel.

This is my mainwindow xaml with the ItemsControl

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UserControlSolution" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="UserControlSolution.MainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="836" Width="270.5" Background="#FF232323" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource Border}" Loaded="Window_Loaded" >

<Window.Resources>

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="Border" EndPoint="0.5,1" MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" StartPoint="0.5,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#FF6C6C6C" Offset="0.009"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFA1A1A1" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel Name="Container" Margin="0,10,0,0">
    <ItemsControl x:Name="UserContainer" ItemsSource="{Binding allUserViewModel.Users}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:UserControlButton />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

Code behind:

```
using UserControlSolution.ViewModel;
using UserControlSolution.Models;

namespace UserControlSolution
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public AllUserViewModel allUserViewModel { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DwmDropShadow.DropShadowToWindow(this);

            allUserViewModel = new AllUserViewModel();

            allUserViewModel.AddUser(new User(1, "Robby", "Bezet"));
            allUserViewModel.AddUser(new User(2, "Erwin", "Bezet"));
            allUserViewModel.AddUser(new User(3, "Laurens", "Bezet"));
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Dock window to right side of the screen
            AppBarFunctions.SetAppBar(this, ABEdge.Right);

            this.DataContext = allUserViewModel;
        }
    }
}
```

And the viewmodel:

```
using UserControlSolution.Models;

namespace UserControlSolution.ViewModel
{
    public class AllUserViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        ObservableCollection<UserViewModel> _users;

        public AllUserViewModel()
        {
            Users = new ObservableCollection<UserViewModel>();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Observable Collection of Users
        /// Uses INotifyPropertyChange when list changes
        /// </summary>
        public ObservableCollection<UserViewModel> Users
        {
            get { return _users; }
            set
            {
                if (_users != value)
                {
                    _users = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Users");
                }
            }
        }

        public void AddUser(User user)
        {
            UserViewModel userViewModel = new UserViewModel(user);
            Users.Add(userViewModel);
        }

        public UserViewModel GetUser(int ID)
        {
            foreach (UserViewModel u in Users)
            {
                if(u.ID == ID)
                    return u;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Why are there no items shown in the ItemsControl when I run this? 
This is the first time I use ItemsControl.

Comment: UserControlButton code  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your itemsSource binding to just  `ItemsSource="{Binding Users}">` because the `DataContext` for your window is already alluserViewmodel